# Inputs required on Regex notepad ++ (updating specific row)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to update specific rows starting with 0500 and update positions 31 to 35, 41 to 45  with 00000 in notepad ++ using regex. Is it something possible ? positive feedback will be really appreciated.

Code tried and got no luck

**Find**: `∆(0500){1}(.{5,30}).{5}(.{36,40}).{5}` 
**Replace**: `\1\200000\300000`
**Mode**: *Regular Expression*

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Find:    ^(0500.{26}).{5}(.{5}).{5}
Replace: \100000\200000
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(0500.{26})` - Group 1 (`\1`): `0500` and any 26 chars other than line break chars
- `.{5}` - any 5 chars other than line break chars
- `(.{5})` - Group 2 (`\2`): any 5 chars other than line break chars
- `.{5}` - any 5 chars other than line break chars

Comment: I am able to register zero's on suggested positions. Many Thanks :)